# "for" about table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
tablelogin = {0 = "test1",1 = "test2",2 = "test3",3 = "test4"}

for pp=0,#table do
  if takeinternalogin == (tablelogin[pp]) then
    LogPrint("Login found")
  else
    LogPrint("failed login not found")
  end
end
```

`takeinternalogin` is an internal function of my program that takes the person's login.

In this script I'm taking the person's login and comparing whether or not the login is in the table.

It works, but after the `else` if the person's login is not in the table, it returns the message "failed login not found" 4 times, that is, it returns the number of times it checks the table.

I don't understand. How can I make the message execute only 1 time?

Comment: The first line is not valid Lua code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently printing the error message every time it iterates over the table and the current value does not match.

```
local arr = {[0] = "test1", [1] = "test2", [2] = "test3", [3] = "test4"}

function findLogin(input)
  for i,v in pairs(tablelogin) do
    if v == input then
      LogPrint("Login found")

      return i
    end
  end

  LogPrint("failed login not found")
end

login = findLogin(takeinternalogin)
```

Using **return** within a loop makes it break out of the loop and in this case never reach the line where it prints the error.

Comment: Hello, despite my example with errors, you managed to understand the question and help me!
Really.. needed a "return", I was analyzing your post and I managed to fix it here, it was perfect.
I'm starting in lua, I'm going to study more about it.
thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

first of all `table` is Lua's table library. You should not use it as a variable name. Unless you've added numeric fields to that table or replaced it with something else `#table` should be 0 and hence your loop should not do anything.

But as you say your loop runs 4 times I suppose you modified `table`.

You say `internallogin` is a function so you can never enter the if block as you compare a function value cannot equal a string value: `takeinternalogin == (tablelogin[pp]`  is always false! `takeinternallogin` would have to return a string.

Why you're using #table here in the first place is unclear to me.

Comment: sorry,I was very sleepy when I asked the question,
I made some mistakes.

Below I will leave the script with the errors corrected (only for the purpose of you to understand the question),
because I can't edit the post anymore.

`tablelogin = {[0]="test1",[1]="test2",[2]="test3",[3]="test4"}
for pp=0,#tablelogin do
local takeinternalogin = "test1"
if takeinternalogin == (tablelogin[pp]) then
print("Login found")
else
print("failed login not found")
end
end`

thanks for your interaction on the question, I solved the problem, with the answer just below the "Cupcake R".